# CSS displaying one box incorrectly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

We have a client whose website which has been working for a few years with no problem. Suddenly we have one block that is not displaying correctly, but only seems to affect Google Chrome:

I guess this is a CSS issue, but we can't figure our what the problem is. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is because, one of your `box` is of different height than that of other `boxes`. Check your code using `developer tools` and find their `height` This usually happens when `unequal-height` `boxes` are floated and then get on next line due to container `width`

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Make an effort to solve the problem. If you run into a specific issue doing so, post a question with your attempt (including all the relevant code), saying what isn't working, and explaining your research so far.

Comment: Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
.carContainer .mix {
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
    min-height: 350px;
}
```

Some boxes are more than `262px` height

Answer (score 0):

Please give a specific height to the div "car-image-grid".

```
.car-image-grid{
  /*Height*/
 }
```

I think your image height.

Answer (score 0):

The boxes height is not equal, try something like this:

```
.carContainer .mix {
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.car-image-grid img {height: 215px;}

/* change min-height to height */

.carOverview {height: 95px;}